# Como rotar un glutWireTorus en OpenGL usando java en netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, opengl

ando haciendo un proyecto de un carro en movimiento en OpenGL y tengo problemas para la rotación fija (horaria y antihoraria )desde el origen  en este caso se trata del “glutWireTorus”

El siguiente código se encarga de dibujar las llantas

`//Tires
//Left Tire
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glRotatef(tireAngle, 0, 0, 1);
gl.glColor3f(1,1,1);
gl.glTranslatef(-0.55f, -1.5f, -6.0f);
gl.glRotatef(-60,1,0,10);
//Draw's solid tire
glut.glutSolidTorus(.1, .21, 5, 25);

```
    //gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glColor3f(1,0,0);
    //Draw's wire tire above of the previous tire
    glut.glutWireTorus(.1, .21, 5, 25);
    //gl.glEnd();
    
    
    //Right Tire
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glRotatef(tireAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glColor3f(1,1,1);
    gl.glTranslatef(1.59f, -1.5f, -6.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(-60,1,0,10);
    //Draw's solid tire
    glut.glutSolidTorus(.1, .21, 5, 25);
    
    //gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glColor3f(1,0,0);
    //Draw's wire tire above of the previous tire
    glut.glutWireTorus(.1, .21, 5, 25);
    //gl.glEnd();
```

`

Uso la variable `float tireAngle = 0.0f` para almacenar el valor del angulo con el que girara la llanta.

y el siguiente metodo se encarga de recibir la tecla y dar el movimiento de rotacion segun sea:

```
glCanvas.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyChar()) {
        case 'h':  // Rotación en sentido horario
            tireAngle += 1.0f;
            break;
        case 'a':  // Rotación en sentido antihorario
            tireAngle -= 1.0f;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    glCanvas.display();  // Redibujar la escena
}
});
```